# Expected flat FFT

Tags: fft

I want to qualify a speaker I use. I use that sound on my speaker to qualify it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNf9nzvnd1k&t=4s

My first question is about the file itself. When I use Audacity the FFT analysis is that way:

[image]

I don't understand why the curve is that way. The magnitude of the input signal seems to be equal, only the frequency is changing.

Can someone explain me that ?

Answer (score 4):

That's a so called logarithmic sweep (or chirp) signal.

The idea here is that the file slowly excites all frequencies sequentially. The sweep rate is "constant relative bandwidth", i.e. it takes the same amount of time for frequency doubling. It takes the same time to get from 125Hz to 250Hz as it takes to get from 250Hz to 500Hz or from 8000Hz to 16000Hz.

This makes the FFT spectrum pink (falling with 3dB/octave) since the FFT uses a linear frequency grid. If you analyze the same signal with an octave or third-octave analyzer, you would see a flat curve.

Logarithmic is used for a variety of reasons:

1. Human pitch perception works this way
2. The signal spectrum is a better match for typical acoustic background noise. With a white signal you will have very poor signal to noise ratio at low frequencies
3. It's a good match for most "real world" audio signals such as speech, music or video

The sweep signal also allows for multiple different ways to calculate the actual transfer function from the measured response, but I guess we leave this for the next question.

Answer (score 1):

When you compute the FFT of the entire signal you will see the energy for each frequency, so the energy accumulated arround each frequency will depend on how fast the frequency is changing.

The freuqency is being swept at an exponential rate, to give the perception of tone shifting linearly, so the time it will play 1kHz is 10x less than the time it will play 100Hz.